# Update Cordova 9 with cordova-ios 5 wanings

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Updated to Cordova 9, getting many warnings when execute

```
cordova build ios
```

I investigated the error by rolling back to Cordova 8 and removing the platforms and added them back then there is no warnings. Cordova-ios is version 4.

I updated to Cordova 9 and everything works fine. However, when I remove platform and add them back using Cordova 9, that is when the warnings appear.

When using Cordova 9 and installing cordova-ios platform then the version is 5 and this is when I receive the warnings.

It requires to make changes in the files generated by cordova which I do not want to do. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

And what error do you get exactly? It's hard to diagnose an error this way...

Anyway, why do you need the latest Cordova 9 version? If your app works fine in the latest iOS emulator, you should avoid newest Cordova versions because it's very common to get errors in these new versions. I wouldn't switch to Cordova 9 unless something is seriously broken with the current implementation, or some critical plugin requires it.

Comment: There are many warnings. Majority similar to this: platforms/ios/Project Name/Plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/CDVStatusBar.m:271:44: warning 

'setStatusBarStyle:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use -[UIViewController
      preferredStatusBarStyle] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:style]; 

The app works when using Cordova 8 and 9. These are only warnings and it would be better to know the reason so I get rid of them

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are just that, warnings. You should not fix them yourself in your project, but report them in cordova-ios [github repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios) so they can be removed in next releases. (If you want to fix them, you can always send a pull request that will benefit all Cordova users)

But as long as your app works I wouldn't worry to much about them.